# How can I name my log files according to the date?

Tags: bash, cron, fish

I have tried to do something like date=date and then name my file $date.txt but the output was date.txt.

Fun thing, I asked Copilot to help but I don't understand its advice and unsure how to fix it:

**Crontab**

```
# run the main script and outputs to a different file every day
20 12 * * * python3 export/main.py > export/logs/$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).log 2>&1
```

Oh by the way I'd like it to work with Fish shell or maybe understand how to forward a command from fish to bash.

Comment: `cron` runs on its own thing (shell?) and does not have all the environmental variable in your default shell.  You may have to specify the full path of the commands you want `cron` to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Fish or your copilot advice but in order to save the output of a **command** into a **variable** in bash the syntax is:

```
variable_name="$(command)"
```

So to save the output of `date` to variable *date* you should do this:

```
date="$(date)"
```

Although since the default output of `date` command contains spaces, I recommend you use some thing like `$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d)` instead of just `$(date)`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
export/logs/$(date --iso-8601 | tr --delete -).log
```

today (April 23) this yields

```
export/logs/20230423.log
```

I find this date format convenient because very concise and can be sorted: example

```
/empty/export/logs$ ls -l
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:23 20220423.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:23 20230423.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:24 20230513.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:24 20230523.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:24 20240423.log
/empty/export/logs$ ls -lr
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:24 20240423.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:24 20230523.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:24 20230513.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:23 20230423.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zzzz users 0 Apr 23 07:23 20220423.log
```